# Dynamic Form Vue.js Detect Input Changes

Tags: vue.js

I need to detect changes from tax input to update the total but I don't know if there is any way.

My data

```
data() {
                return {
                    generalLedgers: [{
                        particulars: '',
                        chart_account_id: '',
                        debit_amount: 0,
                        tax: 0,
                        credit_amount: 0
                    },
                    {
                        particulars: '',
                        chart_account_id: '',
                        debit_amount: 0,
                        tax: 0,
                        credit_amount: 0
                    }],
                    // selectedChartAccount: 0
                }
            }
```

As you can see in my data... it is an array of objects.

```
<div class="row" v-for="(gl, index) in generalLedgers" :key="index">

        <div class="col-xs-1">
           <input-price label="Tax" :value="gl.tax" v-model="gl.tax"></input-price>
        </div>

</div>
```

My Input price component

```
<template>
      <q-input
        type="text"
        :float-label="label"
        prefix="₱"
        v-model="displayValue"
        @blur="isInputActive = false"
        @focus="isInputActive = true"
        :disable="disabled"
      />

    </template>

        <script>
        export default {
          props: ['value', 'label', 'disabled'],
          data: () => ({
            isInputActive: false
          }),
          computed: {
            displayValue: {
              get: function () {
                if (this.isInputActive) {
                  // Cursor is inside the input field. unformat display value for user
                  return this.value.toString()
                } else {
                  // User is not modifying now. Format display value for user interface
                  return this.value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)?$)/g, '$1,')
                }
              },
              set: function (modifiedValue) {
                // Recalculate value after ignoring "$" and "," in user input
                let newValue = parseFloat(modifiedValue.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''))
                // Ensure that it is not NaN
                if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                  newValue = 0
                }
                // Note: we cannot set this.value as it is a "prop". It needs to be passed to parent component
                // $emit the event so that parent component gets it
                this.$emit('input', newValue)
              }
            }
          }
        }
        </script>
```

The tax works fine and update if I add new object. It also updates when I type... The problem is I need to detect if someone will type.

I have use watch but it doesn't work.

```
watch: {
          'gl.tax'(val){
              console.log('asdf')
          }
        }
```

I can detect if the `generalLedgers` was changed using watch

```
 'generalLedgers'(val){
            let debit_amount = _.sumBy(val, function(i) { return i.debit_amount; })
            let tax = _.sumBy(val, function(i) { return i.tax; })
            let total_amount = debit_amount + tax;
            this.$store.dispatch('transactions/transactionTotalAmount', total_amount)

        }
```

The `generalLedgers` works fine if it changed. The only problem is I need to detect the tax when it changed although it updates the `generalLedgers` but I need to detect it to be able to compute again the the total amount. TY

My problem is similar to this https://jsfiddle.net/gzprj5ef/1/
but you need to detect the `input.title` model.

Comment: You should be able to add an input event to the `input-price` element to call a compute total method whenever an input changes `<input-price @input="computeTotal(gl, index)">`

Comment: Thanks I solved it by using `this.$watch('generalLedgers', function(val){
            console.log('asdf')
        }, {
                deep: true
                })`